# Two select statements in one query

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to get the users age by his ID. Easy.
The problem is, at the first time I don't know their IDs, the only thing I know is that it is in a specific table, let's name it "second".

```
SELECT `age` FROM `users` WHERE `userid`=(SELECT `id` FROM `second`)
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example

```
SELECT `age` FROM `users` WHERE `userid`=
  (SELECT `id` FROM `second`  
   WHERE `second`.`name` = 'Berna')
```

should have worked as long as you add a where criteria. This is called subqueries, and is supported in MySQL 5. Reference http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/comparisons-using-subqueries.html

Answer (score 6):

```
SELECT age FROM users WHERE userid IN (SELECT id FROM second)
```

This should work

Answer (score 2):

`SELECT 
    age 
FROM 
    users 
inner join 
   Second 
       on
          users.UserID = second.ID`

An inner join will be more efficient than a sub-select

Comment: Not always. And besides efficiency, there is correctness. This query and the OP's with the `IN` subquery will not yield same results.

Comment: From my understanding the only time a subquery is not out performed by an inner join is when the subquery is changed to an inner join by the optimizer.  In which case they run equally of course.
Out of curiousity did I miss something, will the domain of answers not be the same?? The OP didn't specify a subquery with an in, just seemed to me the OP was using a pseudo code(granted VERY close to correct) to indicate his/her needs. Otherwise we may have just said  
`WHERE Userid=(SELECT top 1 id FROM second)`

Comment: The difference between `IN` with subquery and a `JOIN` is that the Join may produce multiple results (many identical ages in this case). If `id` is the Primary Key, then this will not happen. And you are right, that in MySQL, `IN` is not optimized in the best way. But in general, the statement "a JOIN will be more efficient than a sub-select" is not true.

Comment: Good point about the primary key.  I suppose I saw ID and just assumed a distinct list.  If that's not the case you're right the domain will differ. +1 comment to you :p

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT age FROM users WHERE userid IN (SELECT id FROM second)
```

but preferably

```
SELECT u.age FROM users u INNER JOIN second s ON u.userid = s.id
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the 'in' statement:

```
select * from a
    where x=8 and y=1 and z in (
        select z from b where x=8 and active > '2010-01-07 00:00:00' group by z
    )
```